# Invalid value: "The edited file failed validation": ValidationError(Service.spec): unknown field "nodePort" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.ServiceSpec

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

In order to access the Kubernetes Dashboard remotely, I have tried to replace the `ClusterIP` with `nodePort` as recomended [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Accessing-Dashboard---1.7.X-and-above) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54130046/how-can-i-access-to-kubernetes-dashboard-using-nodeport-in-a-remote-cluster-for). However the edit always fails with the following error:

```
Invalid value: "The edited file failed validation": ValidationError(Service.spec): unknown field "nodePort" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.ServiceSpec
```

The command recommended by the references above is:

```
kubectl edit svc/kubernetes-dashboard --namespace=kube-system
```

Here is the `yaml` what I was trying after changing:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata
  creationTimestamp: "2019-07-24T13:03:48Z"
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "2238"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard
  uid: 79c37d2b-ae13-11e9-b2a1-0026b95c3009
spec:
  NodePort: 10.110.154.246
  ports:
    - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9090
 selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
 sessionAffinity: None
 type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

And the output of client and server version is as follows:

```
   $kubectl version
   Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.2", GitCommit:"cff46ab41ff0bb44d8584413b598ad8360ec1def", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-01-10T23:35:51Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
   Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.8", GitCommit:"0c6d31a99f81476dfc9871ba3cf3f597bec29b58", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-07-08T08:38:54Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Have you checked your spelling of `nodePort` is the correct one. It should be `NodePort`.

Comment: I have tried both `NodePort` and `nodePort`, the same error in both cases.

Comment: Please provide your changed `yaml` manifest what you are applying after changing.

Comment: Also you can provide the version output of command `$ kubectl version`

Comment: Hi, the NodePort should be under the ports sections,  and it should be an integer value

Comment: `kubectl explain svc.spec --recursive` provides all of the skeleton of the svc object.

Comment: @SureshVishnoi still same error after changing the  `NodePort` position.

Comment: Have you kept the `spec.clusterIP: <>.<>.<>.<>` like this line in your changed yaml?
If yes, remove it

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma I also took that away `(spec.clusterIP: <>.<>.<>.<>)`. Same error `ValidationError(Service.spec): unknown field "NodePort" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.ServiceSpec`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally reinstalled the `Kuberbetes Dashboard`, here is the final version of the file that worked following the guide given [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Accessing-Dashboard---1.7.X-and-above) .

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
    {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"k8s- 
  app":"kubernetes-dashboard"},"name":"kubernetes-dashboard","namespace":"kube- 
  system"},"spec":{"ports":[{"port":443,"targetPort":8443}],"selector":{"k8s- 
  app":"kubernetes-dashboard"}}}
creationTimestamp: "2019-07-24T15:20:27Z"
labels:
   k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
name: kubernetes-dashboard
namespace: kube-system
resourceVersion: "13109"
selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard
uid: 90cb249d-ae26-11e9-b2a1-0026b95c3009
spec:
   clusterIP: 10.109.202.107
   externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
   ports:
   - nodePort: 30255
   port: 443
   protocol: TCP
   targetPort: 8443
selector:
k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
sessionAffinity: None
type: NodePort
status:
    loadBalancer: {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You were using the wrong configuration. There is no field in the `spec` of Kubernetes Service named `NodePort`. The doc you shared told you to change the value of the field `spec.type` from `ClusterIP` to `NodePort`. On the hand, you are adding a new field `spec.NodePort` which is totally invalid. See, https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport

Try like this, while doing `kubectl edit`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata
  ...
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
  ...
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9090
 ...
 type: NodePort
...
```

Or just run this:

```
kubectl get svc -n kube-system kubernetes-dashboard -o yaml | sed 's/type: ClusterIP/type: NodePort/' | kubectl replace -f -
```

Comment: Does not work unfortunately, there is an error `* spec.clusterIP: Invalid value: "": field is immutable`

Comment: Have you removed the `clusterIP` field from the `spec`?

Comment: Yes, I removed the `ClusterIP` label, and changed the `type` label to `NodePort`, just as your example `yaml`.

Comment: And what's the output? Is that ok now?

Comment: Also, note that the file is auto-generated I guess during the installation of `Kubernetes Dashboard`, I didn't create it myself.

Comment: Actually, it is created by the cluster-bootstraper tool you are using. Btw, is it `minikube` or something others?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196936/discussion-between-sycode-and-shudipta-sharma).