# Unable to access the EC2 Kubernetes dashboard

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I followed [How can I access to kubernetes dashboard using NodePort in a remote cluster for testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54130046/how-can-i-access-to-kubernetes-dashboard-using-nodeport-in-a-remote-cluster-for)

My Kubernetes cluster runs in Amazon EC2 instances and cluster services looks like below

```
$ kubectl get services --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
default       kubernetes             ClusterIP   100.64.0.1      <none>        443/TCP         5h54m
kube-system   kube-dns               ClusterIP   100.64.0.10     <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   5h53m
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard   NodePort    100.68.178.51   <none>        443:31872/TCP   5h47m

$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://api.selumalai.k8s.com
KubeDNS is running at https://api.selumalai.k8s.com/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

I have exposed the NodePort at 31872. If I access the dashboard in browser using

```
$ kubectl  proxy -p 8001 &
$ curl https://api.selumalai.k8s.com:31872
```

Its loading forever. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: 1. Why are you running `kubectl  proxy -p 8001 &`? 2. Make sure your firewall rules allow external traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [`security group`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html) to your instance to allow traffic for port `31872`.

It's explained how to do so [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/237557/how-to-change-an-ec2-instances-security-group).

If you use `kubectl proxy` it can be accessed localy only, which is stated in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/#command-line-proxy):

> ...
>
> ```
> kubectl proxy
> ```
>
> ...
>   **The UI can  *only*  be accessed from the machine where the command is executed. See  `kubectl proxy --help`  for more options.**

Also here is a guide from AWS on how to [Deploy the Kubernetes Dashboard (web UI)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/dashboard-tutorial.html).
You can try running a L7 ELB to expose the Dashboard which is explained [here](https://medium.com/@vinnyjames007/exposing-the-kubernetes-dashboard-with-aws-l7-elb-25fa22700449).

Comment: I added the nodeport 31872 to the security group. I can access dashboard via curl inside  aws ec2 cluster but not outside (in my local machine browser). Should I need to enable something else ?

Comment: Try pining your cluster from the outside. How many nodes does your cluster have? Can You post  output of `kubectl get nodes -owide`